# JDatabaseDriver->replacePrefix( ) Allowed memory size of ... bytes exhausted

Tags: mysql, jdatabase

[Reported via Issue Tracker Item #33711](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=33711&start=50)

When trying to insert a BLOB > 3MB in the database, the following error occurs:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4252768 bytes) in ...\libraries\joomla\database\driver.php on line 1638

Why is `JDatabaseDriver->replacePrefix( )` eating so much memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is basically nothing wrong with `replacePrefix()`.

What actually happens is that you are sending to MySQL a string which is too large for a predefined setting (`max_allowed_packet`) and is reporting the error `MySQL server has gone away`, as explained in *[MySQL server has gone away obstructing import of large dumps.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5292/mysql-server-has-gone-away-obstructing-import-of-large-dumps)*

Now, Joomla thinks this is just a temporary error, and retries the query, re-running the `execute()` method over and over again, till the memory runs out.

The solution to this issue is to increase the value of `max_allowed_packet` under `[mysqld]` in `my.ini` to a larger value.

Comment: Nice detective work!